# Can magnetization measurement give dimensionless susceptibility without knowledge of volume and density of the material

Tags: condensed-matter

In a magnetization measurement (as a function of temperature) experiment, M is measured in emu (1 emu = 1 erg/G). Weight of the sample used in the experiment is known.
Without knowing the volume and density of the sample, can one obtain the dimensionless susceptibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different types of Magnetization (and susceptibility) you can obtain from the experiment: volume Magnetization (which units are emu/$\mathrm{cm}^3$ or G; though I understood that these two types are not completely equivalent) and mass Magnetization (which units are emu/g).

Dimensionless susceptibility is obtained from volume Magnetization.
So without knowing either sample volume or density you can obtain only mass susceptibility which units is $\mathrm{cm^3/g}$ or $\mathrm{emu/g}$.

p.s.: If you use Vibrating Sample Magnetometer for measuring your samples, you measure the magnetic moment (which units are emu), not the magnetization directly.

---

Table of magnetic units

http://www.ieeemagnetics.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=118&Itemid=107